# How to analyse data/voice ratio within a network

Tags: switch, hp, sflow

I would like to analyse data/voice ratio within a network that uses HP switches. I tried to use HPTools that works with sFlow but it does not give good results.

Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Account bug. Please remove down vote.
Thank you for your answer. Voice and data have two different VLAN. Cacti can do it ? Yes I could use a machin with promiscuous port and analyse the trafic but I don't want to do it with Wireshark.

Comment: I am able to capture VLAN specific traffic information with Cacti on Firewalls I don't see why it wont work on a smart switch.

Answer (score 1):

Switch doesn't provide Transportation Layer information and you need this kind of info. One solution could be: use promiscuous port of the switch to get all the traffic, then capture the packets by wireshark and analyze the data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [sFlowTrend](http://www.inmon.com/products/sFlowTrend.php)? The software is free, displays transport layer flows, and automatically configures sFlow on ProCurve switches using the sFlow MIB. The article, [Five W's](http://blog.sflow.com/2011/06/five-ws.html), describes how to use sFlow/sFlowTrend to monitor traffic and troubleshoot network problems.

Comment: Thank you ! This software is really good. I've also tried a software of SolarWinds which gives good results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of switch you have precisely but if you can tag your traffic that would be a start.

You can also use tools that rely on [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol).

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) are pretty common tools.